# Has Ubuntu been patched against the KRACK attack?

Tags: networking, security

According to this [article](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/10/severe-flaw-in-wpa2-protocol-leaves-wi-fi-traffic-open-to-eavesdropping/) a severe flaw in wpa2 protocol has been published making many systems using WiFi vulnerable to an attack. Should I be worried and has a patch been issued for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A fix has been issued as per [USN-3455-1](https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3455-1/) . You should update your system with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. The relevant versions for currently supported releases:

- Ubuntu 17.04:
  hostapd 2.4-0ubuntu9.1
  wpasupplicant 2.4-0ubuntu9.1
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:
  hostapd 2.4-0ubuntu6.2
  wpasupplicant 2.4-0ubuntu6.2
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:
  hostapd 2.1-0ubuntu1.5
  wpasupplicant 2.1-0ubuntu1.5

You should see an update of `wpasupplicant` during the update. More information about the attack is available on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/kristate/krackinfo).

Comment: My Ubuntu 14.4 LTS does not show the minor version: 
`leder@gisela-E7220:~$ dpkg -l wpasupplicant


...


ii  wpasupplicant  2.1-0ubuntu1 amd64        client support for WPA and WPA2 (
`

Comment: @Leder Mine shows `2.1-0ubuntu1.5`, so it seems you're missing the update.

Comment: How can I check if update is already installed?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get changelog wpasupplicant`. You should see something like `SECURITY UPDATE: Multiple issues in WPA protocol`
`- debian/patches/2017-1/*.patch: Add patches from Debian stretch
    - CVE-2017-13077, CVE-2017-13078, CVE-2017-13079, CVE-2017-13080,
      CVE-2017-13081, CVE-2017-13082, CVE-2017-13086, CVE-2017-13087,
      CVE-2017-13088`